# Extraer info de un csv en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, csv

Tengo que extraer de un csv; separado por ";" los campos, en los que tengo que contar que el primer campo sea "V"; y a su vez voy creando un array en el tercer campo.

Yo tengo un código; pero, me imprime todos los campos.

```
function parseCSV(text) {
  // Obtenemos las lineas del texto
  let lines = text.replace(/\r/g, '').split('\n');
  return lines.map(line => {
    // Por cada linea obtenemos los valores
    let values = line.split(';');
    return values;
  });
}

function reverseMatrix(matrix){
  let output = [];
  // Por cada fila
  matrix.forEach((values, row) => {
    // Vemos los valores y su posicion
    values.forEach((value, col) => {
      // Si la posición aún no fue creada
      if (output[col] === undefined) output[col] = [];
      output[col][row] = value;
    });
  });
  return output;
}

function readFile(evt) {
  let file = evt.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    // Cuando el archivo se terminó de cargar
    let lines = parseCSV(e.target.result);
    let output = reverseMatrix(lines);
    console.log(output);
  };
  // Leemos el contenido del archivo seleccionado
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

Más adelante un html:

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar solo la tercera columna (ya sea que la guarde en otro array, o no).
La validación de la "V", sí la sé hacer; por eso no la he preguntado.

Por favor, pido orientación.

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo tu problema.. si estas haciendo un split, estas dejando ya todo en columnas.. solo te quedas con la columna que queres... tal vez no entendi que problema tuviste con eso???

Comment: Muchas gracias; realmente lo que necesito es solamente MOSTRAR los valores de la tercera columna; pero, con el código, me muestra todas

Comment: Ese codigo no muestra nada... donde es que estas mostrando?

Comment: No entendí del todo bien tu pregunta pero por el otro comentario que veo aquí creo que entiendo.  tanto \r como \n suelen ser en muchos casos saltos de columna. Por ello intenta con esto 

  let lines = text.split(/\n|\r/);

Answer (score 0):

Una vez obtenido los datos podemos recorrer el arreglo con forEach y por cada iteracion selecciona la tercera colunna

ejemplo:

```js
['a1;a2;a3','b1;b2;b3','c1;c2;c3'].map(line => {
    // Por cada linea obtenemos los valores
    let values = line.split(';');
    return values;
  }).forEach(el=>{console.log(el[2])})
```

```js
//Leemos la data y la convertimos en un arrego por salto de linea y asignamos a una variable
let data = 
`v;2024-02-15;XYZ123;0
V;2024-02-15;XYZ124,YRW124,XWK124;3
V;2024-02-15;FED56E,ZXS44A;1
v;2024-02-15;AAA001,CFG765;3
p;2024-02-15;17953454;0
V;2024-02-15;UHH123;7
P;2024-02-15;8675321;1
V;2024-02-15;FGR34B,ASD22A;2
p;2024-02-15;1123654098;0
P;2024-02-15;32654023;0
V;2024-02-15;ERP357,ADS22C;1`.split('\n')

//Utilizamos el metodo filter para reducir el tamanio del arreglo y lo asignamos a una variable
let reduceData = data.filter(el=>el.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('v;'))

//Utilizamos el metodo map para crear un nuevo arrego solo con la colunna deseada
console.log(reduceData.map(el=> el.split(';')[2]))

//espero te sea de ayuda
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ramon; voy a reformular la pregunta, para mayor claridad

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/616117/extraer-informaci%c3%b3n-de-un-csv-en-javascript

Comment: he agregado un script que da solucion al problema

Comment: Gracias, @ramon-reynoso ... esto sí era lo que yo necesitaba.
Hay un detalle; y es que me gustaría **después** imprimir, esa tercera columna de forma horizontal; es decir, después del [0][2] el [1][2] y así ... de esta forma: 


`"XYZ123",  "XYZ124,YRW124,XWK124",  "FED56E,ZXS44A",  AAA001,CFG765",  "UHH123",  "FGR34B,ASD22A",  "ERP357,ADS22C"`


gracias

Comment: Yo utilizo el fitro así :

`let reduceData = data.filter(el => /^[vV]$/.test(el));` pues, requiero el uso de expresiones regulares

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que en el siguiente código quieres separar las líneas

```js
function parseCSV(text) {
  // Obtenemos las lineas del texto
  let lines = text.replace(/\r/g, '').split('\n');
  return lines.map(line => {
    // Por cada linea obtenemos los valores
    let values = line.split(';');
    return values;
  });
}
```

Sin embargo, tanto \r como \n son saltos de lineá y en tu función eliminas los saltos \r con el replace antes de separarlos y solo lo estás separando por \n
Creo que tú código debería de verse entonces así:

```js
function parseCSV(text) {
  // Obtenemos las lineas del texto
  let lines = text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
  return lines.map(line => {
    // Por cada linea obtenemos los valores
    let values = line.split(';');
    return values;
  });
}
```

Esto porque algunos sistemas representan los saltos de linea con \r otros con \n y otros con \r\n