# Extraer información de un csv en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, csv

Tengo que extraer de un csv; separado por ";" los campos, en los que tengo que contar que el primer campo sea "V"; y a su vez voy creando un array en el tercer campo.

El archivo lo sube el usuario y es del formato:

```
v;2024-02-15;XYZ123;0
V;2024-02-15;XYZ124,YRW124,XWK124;3
V;2024-02-15;FED56E,ZXS44A;1
v;2024-02-15;AAA001,CFG765;3
p;2024-02-15;17953454;0
V;2024-02-15;UHH123;7
P;2024-02-15;8675321;1
V;2024-02-15;FGR34B,ASD22A;2
p;2024-02-15;1123654098;0
P;2024-02-15;32654023;0
V;2024-02-15;ERP357,ADS22C;1
```

Necesito leer solamente las filas que empiezan por V; pero, eso no lo pregunto, eso lo tengo claro... lo que necesito es un array donde guarde la tercera columna y poder mostrarla como una lista separada por comas.

Yo tengo un código; pero, me imprime todos los campos.

```
function parseCSV(text) {
  // Obtenemos las lineas del texto
  let lines = text.replace(/\r/g, '').split('\n');
  return lines.map(line => {
    // Por cada linea obtenemos los valores
    let values = line.split(';');
    return values;
  });
}

function reverseMatrix(matrix){
  let output = [];
  // Por cada fila
  matrix.forEach((values, row) => {
    // Vemos los valores y su posicion
    values.forEach((value, col) => {
      // Si la posición aún no fue creada
      if (output[col] === undefined) output[col] = [];
      output[col][row] = value;
    });
  });
  return output;
}

function readFile(evt) {
  let file = evt.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    // Cuando el archivo se terminó de cargar
    let lines = parseCSV(e.target.result);
    let output = reverseMatrix(lines);
    console.log(output);
  };
  // Leemos el contenido del archivo seleccionado
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

Más adelante un html:

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

Por favor, pido orientación.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, no es necesario crear una nueva pregunta para agregar más información. Utiliza la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/616072/extraer-info-de-un-csv-en-javascript) tu pregunta original.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos ; pensé que no era bueno... por que ya me habían respondido